# Name or notation for $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\ast\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\ast\cdots\ast \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, notation

Is there a standard notation for the n-fold free product of a group with itself? In particular, I'd like to know a nice name or notation for the the $n$-fold free product of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ with itself.

Comment: Reverted to asterisks because the OP was not referring to the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 5):

I have repeatedly seen $G^{*n}$ as a notation for the n-fold free product. It seems clear and unambiguous enough for me.